# scrapy isn't making all request

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to download a list of pages, I'm not extracting any data at this moment so I only saving the response.body in a csv file.

I'm not crawling either, so the start urls are the only urls I need to get, I've a list of 400 urls

```
start_urls =['url_1','url_2,'url_3',---,'url_400']
```

but I'm only getting the source for about 170, no clue of what;s happening with the rest.

this is the log I got at the end

```
2016-05-16 04:30:25 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-05-16 04:30:25 [scrapy] INFO: Stored csv feed (166 items) in: pages.csv
2016-05-16 04:30:25 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 11,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError': 6,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseFailed': 5,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 95268,
 'downloader/request_count': 180,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 180,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 3931169,
 'downloader/response_count': 169,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 166,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 3,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 16, 9, 0, 25, 461208),
 'item_scraped_count': 166,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 350,
 'log_count/INFO': 17,
 'response_received_count': 169,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 180,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 180,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 180,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 180,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 16, 8, 50, 34, 443699)}
2016-05-16 04:30:25 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: can you provide the full code of your spider?

Comment: is it possible that some of those urls are repeated? Scrapy ignores repeated urls by default

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida it's possible but unlikely to have that many duplicate urls, I'll check.